# Weblogic 10 - JMS - This RJVM has already been shutdown

Tags: jms, weblogic

Any idea why the following errors comes up.This is happening when posting a JMS message to a queue deployed on Admin server from the application on managed server.

009-06-02 11:21:18,688 (com.xxx.util.servicelocator.ServiceLocator:612) ERROR - Error while loading Queue ProfilerNotify

javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: This RJVM has already been shutdown 3481854169479569584S:XX.XXX.X.XXX:[9200,9200,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:Production10:AdminServer]

```
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:64)

        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.translateException(WLContextImpl.java:426)

        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:382)

        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:367)

        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:351)

        at com.xxx.util.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.loadQueue(ServiceLocator.java:607)

        at com.xxx.util.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.getQueue(ServiceLocator.java:285)
```

Answer (score 2):

We had this error in what sounded like similar circumstances recently.

It turned out to be because we didn't have the domain names of the servers in DNS. We weren't using domain names (we used IPs) but it seems weblogic needs to be able to reverse-lookup IP addresses or it gives this most misleading error.

We just added the relevant lines to /etc/hosts and everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is DNS name resolution issue. Though I added the entry in /etc/hosts in my application server but the same needs to be added in the foreign server as it was not able to resolve the DNS. 
The other way around what I found (w/o any entry in /etc/hosts) was that in Weblogic Console-->Server-->Managed Server-->General Tab-->Listen Address field I had given the hostname of my managed server. I changed it to IP address of my Managed server and then was able to connect to the Foreign Server. The More Info section of Listen Address field says few things about giving DNS names:

To resolve a DNS name to an IP address, WebLogic Server must be able to contact an appropriate DNS server or obtain the IP address mapping locally. Therefore, if you specify a DNS name for the listen address, you must either leave a port open long enough for the WebLogic Server instance to connect to a DNS server and cache its mapping or you must specify the IP address mapping in a local file. If you specify an IP address for ListenAddress and then a client request specifies a DNS name, WebLogic Server will attempt to resolve the DNS name, but if it cannot access DNS name mapping, the request will fail